# Set Default Policy for all of user on kerberos ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kerberos, ubuntu-20.04

I am confused when creating a password policy in kerberos ubuntu, what I don't know is how to make the policy that we have created become the default and how to make the policy apply to users that we have created before? please help, thank you.

Comment: `make the policy apply to users that we have created before` expiring the password usually works.

Comment: What KDC software are you using?